# Elasticsearch: How to calculate the yield (percentage of success)?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, aggregation, rate

My purpose is to calculate the yield of each benchId. Which means: For each bench, what is the percentage of team that have isPassed=True the first time they pass the test. I would like to have a visualization of each yield for each bench.

My Elasticsearch mapping is:

```
  "test-logs" : {
"mappings" : {
  "log" : {
    "properties" : {
      "benchGroup" : {
        "type" : "keyword"
      },
      "benchId" : {
        "type" : "keyword"
      },
      "date" : {
        "type" : "date",
        "format" : "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
      },
      "duration" : {
        "type" : "float"
      },
      "finalStatus" : {
        "type" : "keyword"
      },
      "isCss" : {
        "type" : "boolean"
      },
      "isPassed" : {
        "type" : "boolean"
      },
      "machine" : {
        "type" : "keyword"
      },
      "sha1" : {
        "type" : "keyword"
      },
      "uuid" : {
        "type" : "keyword"
      },
      "team" : {
        "type" : "keyword"
      }
```

I tried to divide this issue in several sub-issues. I think I need to aggregate the documents by benchId then sub-aggregate them by team, ordering them by date then taking the first document. Then I think need to use a script to calculate isPassed=True/all first attemps.
No idea how to visualize the result on Kibana though.

I manage to create aggregations with this search:

```
GET _search
    {
       "size" : 0,
       "aggs": {
         "benchId": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "benchId"
             },
             "aggs": {
                 "teams": {
                      "terms": {
                          "script": "doc['uut'].join(' & ')",
                          "size": 10
                       }
                  }
              }
          }
       }
    }
```

I get the result I want but I have difficulties to include order by date ascending with limitation to one document by uut